# CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS([Lorg.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback) :

Tags: spring-boot, junit, powermockito, testcase, cglib

Some Junit Test cases are failing when running all test classes together but passing individually.

**Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: xxx.zzz$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS([Lorg.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback;)
**        at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(ExampleClass.java:2675) ~[data-feeder.exe:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getCallbacksSetter(Enhancer.java:901) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer$EnhancerFactoryData.(Enhancer.java:490) ~[na:na]
... 40 common frames omitted

Any answer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.